# Is there a way to count checkboxes based on column header AND sync that based on Student ID #?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my Google Sheets spreadsheet, I want to calculate the number of times a student earned a checkbox for certain criteria (column headers - Row 3).
[Assignment Tab Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmdJN.png)

In another tab, I want to be able to calculate how many times Karen (see spreadsheet) earned a checkmark in a column with the "CTE1" header and return that value to cell E3.
[Report Tab 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NGSD.png)

I was able find a formula to count the entire row based on Column Header (Row 3) but it is not connected to the Student ID #, so if I sort the data it misaligns the data.

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C_Bwn7YUbgaPVmj7Ids6aeNNdvitadpjVNyhtTJjeZ4/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Assignments!$3:$3,{$F$1},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(offset(Assignments!$1:$1,MATCH(C3,Assignments!C:C,0)-1,),{TRUE},0)))
```

in that formula, I search for C3 within column C `MATCH(C3,Assignments!C:C,0)` and then `offset` the first line by the value minus 1